# MaterialCalendarView not occupying full width android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am placing a Material calendar view and i want the calendar height to occupy half of the screen and it was made by using layout weight but the calendar not occupying the full width.
one more problem is that I want to increase the text size of the date please refer me any idea

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="symphony.acube.com.symphony.activity.patient.acitivity.mySchedule.MyScheduleActivity">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"></include>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/llCalendarContainer"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/calendarView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
                app:mcv_selectionColor="@color/toolbar_red"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

The following is the actual window i am getting currently

[image]

In the above calendar should occupy full width and also the text size of the date must be some big 
Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

To stretch the width of the calendar should:

The measureTileSize reduce by a factor of (in the method onMeasure class MaterialCalendarView)

```
int childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec ((int) (p.height * (measureTileSize / 1.5)), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
```

The same is done in the `MonthView`

```
int childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec ((int) (measureTileSize / 1.5), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
```

Something come up with the background (stretched into an oval)

For more follow this [issue](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/issues/132)

Comment: Thankyou @Zeeshan Shabbir for your response.But I don't know where to implement the above code.since i am a newbie please tolerate me

Comment: Please go through the issue that i mentioned in the answer. Each and everything is in there. I hope it will help you if you throughly read the issue and explore the libaray classes